Is there a way to use parameters in Databricks in SQL with parameter marker syntax (:param) inside create view?
EDIT:
I got a message from Databricks' employee that currently (DBR 15.4 LTS) the parameter marker syntax is not supported in this scenario. It might work in the future versions.
Original question:
In Databricks (on Azure) I'd like to write a query with :param notation (parameter marker syntax) that would work as this one:
create or replace temporary view vvv1 as (
  
  select *
  from ${catalog}.${schema}.table_name
  limit 10

)

The above one gives a warning:

SQL query contains $ parameter. Migrate to the parameter marker syntax, :param:

I tried these two:
declare or replace p_vvv2 = 'catalog.schema.table_name';

create or replace temporary view vvv2 as (
  
  select *
  from identifier(:p_vvv2)
  limit 10

)

create or replace temporary view vvv3 as (
  
  select *
  from identifier(:catalog || '.' || :schema || '.table_name')
  limit 10

)

both giving an error:

[UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE.PARAMETER_MARKER_IN_UNEXPECTED_STATEMENT] The feature is not supported: Parameter markers are not allowed in CREATE VIEW body. SQLSTATE: 0A000

What is the proper way to replace ${param} to :param in this scenario?


Named parameters/mustache parameters can be used only in Select, not as Views.

Even as a pure Select statement, your usage of {} is incorrect. It should be {{ }}, not ${} like Bash statements.


Please follow this for more info.
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/user/queries/query-parameters.html#syntax-changes

The ${param} syntax is the only that I found working so far but it gives warning that I should migrate to :param. The problem is I don't see a way to replace it.

Are you using ${} with Python using spark.sql or in SQL Editor?

I'm using it in a notebook with SQL Serverless compute. The final idea is to run it as a job with parameters. The catalog and schema should dynamically change for DEV, UAT, and PROD environments.

Hope you are looking for catalog and schema should dynamically change for DEV, UAT, and PROD environments and via notebooks.
If environment is the only case, then you can also handle those like below (one of the ways), without even params as well:
# assign workspace dynamically based on environments & create value for catalog_schema
devWorkspaceID = ['']
qaWorkspaceID = ['']
prodWorkspaceID = ['']

currentWorkspaceID = spark.conf.get('spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterOwnerOrgId')

if currentWorkspaceID in devWorkspaceID:
  catalog_schema = 'dev_catalog.schema'
elif currentWorkspaceID in qaWorkspaceID:
  catalog_schema = 'qa_catalog.schema'
elif currentWorkspaceID in prodWorkspaceID:
  catalog_schema = 'prod_catalog.schema'
  
print(catalog_schema)

#mention at start itself our write path
write_path = f"{catalog_schema}.write_table_name"

#mention at start itself our read path & create views
df_read = spark.sql(f"""select * from {catalog_schema}.read_table_name""")
df_read.createOrReplaceTempView("view_1")

#apply all transformations in between via view.

#load final transformed o/p into the write path table.
df_write = spark.sql("select * from view_1")
df_write.write.mode('append').saveAsTable(write_path)


That of course works but I was looking for a solution purely in SQL so that I could run it on SQL Serverless.

A couple things:

Databricks demands the use of the IDENTIFIER() clause when using widgets to reference objects including tables, fields, etc., which is exactly what you're doing.  See here for details: https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/widgets.html

It still can't be used in a temporary view unfortunately, but it can work in a Common Table Expression (CTE) using a with() statement


    with t1 as -- use the CTE with your SELECT statements to leverage the widget value
    (select
       *
    from 
      identifier(:p_vvv2)
    limit 10
    )
    select * from t1


